# Using C# Code in a .JS file?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2015

Just curious if it is possible, I have a C# WFA Project, and I want to be able to import some .js files I have laying around for a multi-purpose tool I am making, I have the .js file in my project, is there any possible way where I can write like form1.textBox1.Text in the js file, like add a reference from the C# file(s) to it or something? Just asking if it's possible.

Comment: What's your requirement? Using C# in middle of js file is meaningless.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well I have something that is written in .js and inside of it there is code where you type in `'email@email.com' : 'password'` and then you save the file and open the account.html and it views your accounts info from the game I made it for, and now I wanna make it a little bit better and implement it in my multi-purpose tool and I have 2 textBoxes, one for user and the other for password and I want to write basically in the .js file `"'" + textBox1.Text + "' : '" + textBox2.Text "'"`

Comment: Do you mean you want to write some text in js file and save it using C#/WindowsForms?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the asp controls using JQuery as follows

Your `.ascx/.aspx`

```
<div id='form_holder'>
  <asp:TextBox id='txtEmail' runat='server' />
  <asp:TextBox id='txtPassword' runat='server' />
</div>
```

Your `.js`

```
function foo() {
    var txts = $("#form_holder").find("input[type=text]");
    var email = txts[0].value;
    var passwd = txts[1].value;
}
```